# Gastby - Add a GraphQL query with parameters in gastby-node.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

Inside `gatsby-node.js`I have two queries that gets its data from Contentful. I want to add a new query that loads the data for a particular content based on its `slug` (a field set in the content model in Contentful).

This is what I have:

```js
  return graphql(
    `
      {
        allContentfulBlogPost {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
            }
          }
        }
        allContentfulCaseStudy(filter: { slug: { ne: "dummy-content" } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
            }
          }
        }
        contentfulCaseStudy(slug: { eq: $slug }) { // <=== Here is the problem
          title
          overview
        }
      }
    `
  )
    .then(result => {
      if (result.errors) {
        console.log("Error retrieving contentful data", result.errors)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error retrieving contentful data", error)
    })
}
```

So, I want to query that particular case study passing the `slug` in `contentfulCaseStudy(slug: { eq: $slug })` but it doesn't work. It throws this error when I start `npm run develop`:

```
 ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Variable "$slug" is not defined.

File: gatsby-node.js:13:10

Error retrieving contentful data [
  GraphQLError: Variable "$slug" is not defined.
      at Object.leave (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\graphql\validation\rules\NoUndefinedVariables.js:38:33)
      at Object.leave (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\graphql\language\visitor.js:345:29)
      at Object.leave (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\graphql\language\visitor.js:395:21)
      at visit (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\graphql\language\visitor.js:242:26)
      at validate (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\graphql\validation\validate.js:73:24)
      at GraphQLRunner.validate (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\query\graphql-runner.js:79:44)
      at GraphQLRunner.query (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\query\graphql-runner.js:144:25)
      at C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\create-graphql-runner.js:40:19
      at Object.exports.createPages (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\gatsby-node.js:13:10)
      at runAPI (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\api-runner-node.js:259:37)
      at Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\api-runner-node.js:378:15)
      at Promise._execute (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:384:9)
      at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:518:18)
      at new Promise (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:103:10)
      at C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\api-runner-node.js:377:12
      at tryCatcher (C:\Edited\edited\edited\edited\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23) {
    locations: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
```

Is it possible to request a particular case study passing the slug as parameter? If so, how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't directly. You can filter with a hardcoded parameter, not with a dynamic pre-queried value.

However, what you are trying to do with `$slug` is to pass a variable via [context API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/).

The flow that are you trying to achieve is:

- Fetch and create pages from Contentful data for `allContentfulCaseStudy`
- Use the `slug` of `allContentfulCaseStudy` in `contentfulCaseStudy` to filter your query for each `contentfulCaseStudy`.

So, you need to move your `contentfulCaseStudy` into your `template.js` modifying your `gatsby-node.js` like this:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allContentfulCaseStudy(filter: { slug: { ne: "dummy-content" } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  const caseStudyTemplate= path.resolve(`src/templates/case-study.js`)

  result.data.allContentfulCaseStudy.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path,
      component: caseStudyTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Now, in your `case-study.js` you have available the `slug` variable since you are passing it via `context` in your [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/). So:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function CaseStudy({ data }) {
  const caseStudy= data.contentfulCaseStudy
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{caseStudy.title}</h1>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
        contentfulCaseStudy(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
          title
          overview
        }
  }
`
```

Check your `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to see if the nested `title` and `overview` are under `contentfulCaseStudy` or if you need to modify the query structure.

Further Reading:

- [Creating Pages from Data Programmatically](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/)
- [How to add query variables to a page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query)